# Images appear blank when displaying pdf using html2ps API

Tags: php, pdf-generation

I am working on pdf creation script i am trying to create my pdf using html2ps API. My code works fine with my testing machine having Windows 7 professional edition and php version 5.3.5. Now i have uploaded my files on server(having Linux and php version 5.2.15 ) there is a problem while display of my pictures. My pdf file have no picture but blank space for image. other layout of my page works fine. If any one can help me how i can fix this issue. Here is my code for html2pdf script...

```
_dest_filename = $dest_filename;
      }

      function process($tmp_filename, $content_type) 
      {
        copy($tmp_filename, $this->_dest_filename);
      }
    }

    class MyFetcherMemory extends Fetcher {
      var $base_path;
      var $content;

      function MyFetcherMemory($content, $base_path) {
        $this->content   = $content;
        $this->base_path = $base_path;
      }

      function get_data($url) {
        if (!$url) {
          return new FetchedDataURL($this->content, array(), "");
        } else {
          // remove the "file:///" protocol
          if (substr($url,0,8)=='file:///') {
            $url=substr($url,8);
            // remove the additional '/' that is currently inserted by utils_url.php
            if (PHP_OS == "WINNT") $url=substr($url,1);
          }
          return new FetchedDataURL(@file_get_contents($url), array(), "");
        }
      }

      function get_base_url() {
        return 'file:///'.$this->base_path;
      }
    }

    function convert_to_pdf($html, $path_to_pdf, $base_path='') {
      $pipeline = PipelineFactory::create_default_pipeline('', 
                                                           '');
      $pipeline->fetchers[] = new MyFetcherMemory($html, $base_path);

      // Override destination to local file
      $pipeline->destination = new MyDestinationFile($path_to_pdf);

      $baseurl = '';
      $media =& Media::predefined('A4');
      $media->set_landscape(true);
      $media->set_margins(array('left'   => 40,
                                'right'  => 5,
                                'top'    => 5,
                                'bottom' => 0));
      $media->set_pixels(1024); 

      global $g_config;
      $g_config = array(
                        'cssmedia'     => 'screen',
                        'scalepoints'  => '1',
                        'renderimages' => true,
                        'renderlinks'  => false,
                        'renderfields' => false,
                        'renderforms'  => false,
                        'mode'         => 'php',
                        'encoding'     => '',
                        'debugbox'     => false,
                        'pdfversion'    => '1.4',
                        'ps2pdf'        => 'ps2pdf',

                        'pslevel'       => '1',
                        'draw_page_border' => false
                        );
      $pipeline->configure($g_config);
      $pipeline->process_batch(array($baseurl), $media);
      }
      ?>
```

I have defined a function for getting html

```
function generate_product_pdf($pid)
{
.......my html code 
return $html;
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: How you include the image in your HTML? Check the image URL is correct, no white spaces in the image name, the entire URL is in lowercase, and make sure the path is absolute (e.g. http://yoursite.com/path/to/image.jpg). The script in your question is incomplete or missing and the HTML code would be helpful to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Linux machine probably can't access images by URL that you provide. So its either DNS-related (like hard-coded IP or non-existant domain),  hosting related (like images are in a http-auth protected folder) or error in the code (which can check for OS). Without means to debug it, its hard to tell.